# SQL Server - Can I dynamically create multiple parameters from the results of a SELECT query on another table?

Tags: sql-server, variables, dynamic, parameters

So I have my 'Chaplains' table:

```
CREATE TABLE Chaplaincy_Chaplains
(
ChaplainID INTEGER IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
ChaplainName VARCHAR(50),
FaithID INTEGER,
Telephone VARCHAR(50),
Email VARCHAR(255),
Notes VARCHAR(255),
FOREIGN KEY (FaithID) REFERENCES Chaplaincy_Faiths(FaithID)
);
```

Into which I have inserted four records:

```
INSERT INTO Chaplaincy_Chaplains
VALUES ('Robin Richardson',1,'555-123456','Robin.Richardson@chaplaincy.com',NULL)

INSERT INTO Chaplaincy_Chaplains
VALUES ('Peter Jackson',8,'555-123-456','Peter.Jackson@chaplaincy.com',NULL)

INSERT INTO Chaplaincy_Chaplains
VALUES ('Harry Davidson',1,'555-123-456','Harry.Davidson@chaplaincy.com',NULL)

INSERT INTO Chaplaincy_Chaplains
VALUES ('Steve Morrison',7,'555-123-456','Steve.Morrison@chaplaincy.com',NULL)
```

At the moment I have hard-coded those records into my 'Rota' query:

```
SELECT RotaDate,  DateDay, SlotTypeID, SlotDescription AS Hours,
    max(case when ChaplainName = 'Robin Richardson' then AvailabilityDescription end) Robin ,
    max(case when ChaplainName = 'Peter Jackson' then AvailabilityDescription end) Peter ,
    max(case when ChaplainName = 'Harry Davidson' then AvailabilityDescription end) Harry ,
    max(case when ChaplainName = 'Steve Morrison' then AvailabilityDescription end) Steve 
    FROM Chaplaincy_Rota,Chaplaincy_Availability, Chaplaincy_Chaplains, Chaplaincy_Dates, Chaplaincy_Faiths, Chaplaincy_SlotTypes
    WHERE
    RotaDate = Chaplaincy_Dates.Date AND
    RotaSlot = SlotTypeID AND
    RotaChaplain = ChaplainID AND
    RotaAvailability = AvailabilityID AND
    ChaplainFaith = Chaplaincy_Faiths.FaithID
    GROUP BY RotaDate, SlotTypeID, SlotDescription, DateDay
    ORDER BY RotaDate, SlotTypeID;
```

Which gives me something like this:

```
                                  | Robin  | Peter | Harry   | Steve   |

01/06/2015 | Mon | 00:00 to 08:00 | Leave  | Study | On-call | Avail   |

01/06/2015 | Mon | 08:00 to 13:00 | Leave  | Study | On-call | Avail   |

01/06/2015 | Mon | 13:00 to 18:00 | Leave  | Study | On-call | Avail   |

01/06/2015 | Mon | 18:00 to 00:00 | Leave  | Study | On-call | Avail   |

02/06/2015 | Tue | 00:00 to 08:00 | On-call| Avail | Study   | Avail   |

02/06/2015 | Tue | 08:00 to 13:00 | On-call| Avail | Study   | Avail   |

02/06/2015 | Tue | 13:00 to 18:00 | On-call| Avail | Avail   | Avail   |

02/06/2015 | Tue | 18:00 to 00:00 | On-call| Avail | Avail   | Avail   |
....
et cetera
```

Is there a way I can dynamically update my 'Rota' query, so that every time I add a new record to the 'Chaplains' table, that record will automatically be included in the 'Rota' query? In effect, I want to be able to add a column to the 'Rota' query, just by adding a row to the Chaplains table.

Many thanks for reading!

Comment: Yes there is way. Look for dynamic query and `EXEC` function

Comment: You would either need to use dynamic SQL, or preferably do the pivot in your presentation layer. There are plenty of questions about on this - search for `dynamic pivot` (or search for `bluefeet`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check this

```
Declare @sql varchar(max) = ''
set @sql = 'SELECT RotaDate,  DateDay, SlotTypeID, SlotDescription AS Hours,'

select @sql = @sql + ' 
' + 'max(case when ChaplainName = '''+ChaplainName+''' then AvailabilityDescription end) '+LEFT(ChaplainName, CHARINDEX(' ', ChaplainName+ ' ') - 1)+' ,'
FROM Chaplaincy_Chaplains

SET @sql = LEFT(@sql, LEN(@sql) - 1)

SET @sql = @sql + ' ' +
    '
    FROM Chaplaincy_Rota,Chaplaincy_Availability, Chaplaincy_Chaplains, Chaplaincy_Dates, Chaplaincy_Faiths, Chaplaincy_SlotTypes
    WHERE
    RotaDate = Chaplaincy_Dates.Date AND
    RotaSlot = SlotTypeID AND
    RotaChaplain = ChaplainID AND
    RotaAvailability = AvailabilityID AND
    ChaplainFaith = Chaplaincy_Faiths.FaithID
    GROUP BY RotaDate, SlotTypeID, SlotDescription, DateDay
    ORDER BY RotaDate, SlotTypeID;'

Print @sql
EXEC (@sql)
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
    SELECT RotaDate,  DateDay, SlotTypeID, SlotDescription AS Hours, 
max(case when ChaplainName = 'Robin Richardson' then AvailabilityDescription end) Robin , 
max(case when ChaplainName = 'Peter Jackson' then AvailabilityDescription end) Peter , 
max(case when ChaplainName = 'Harry Davidson' then AvailabilityDescription end) Harry , 
max(case when ChaplainName = 'Steve Morrison' then AvailabilityDescription end) Steve  
    FROM Chaplaincy_Rota,Chaplaincy_Availability, Chaplaincy_Chaplains, Chaplaincy_Dates, Chaplaincy_Faiths, Chaplaincy_SlotTypes
    WHERE
    RotaDate = Chaplaincy_Dates.Date AND
    RotaSlot = SlotTypeID AND
    RotaChaplain = ChaplainID AND
    RotaAvailability = AvailabilityID AND
    ChaplainFaith = Chaplaincy_Faiths.FaithID
    GROUP BY RotaDate, SlotTypeID, SlotDescription, DateDay
    ORDER BY RotaDate, SlotTypeID;
```

Comment: Glad i could help, Please accept the answer if it worked so other's could know it too. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers